# change birthday language liferay hook

Tags: datepicker, calendar, liferay, hook

We are using a Liferay Hook for registration on our project. We have a form with Date of Birth among other user personal data.

Here is the code :

```
  <c:choose>
       <c:when test="<%=PrefsPropsUtil.getBoolean(company.getCompanyId(), PropsKeys.FIELD_ENABLE_COM_LIFERAY_PORTAL_MODEL_CONTACT_BIRTHDAY)%>">
           <aui:input name="birthday" label="birthday" value="<%=birthday%>" />
       </c:when>
       <c:otherwise>
           <aui:input name="birthdayMonth" type="hidden" value="<%=Calendar.JANUARY%>" />
           <aui:input name="birthdayDay" type="hidden" value="1" />
           <aui:input name="birthdayYear" type="hidden" value="1970" />
       </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
```

We have also two different languages for our portal, Spanish and Galician language. When we use Spanish language everything is ok and displays the month names in the correct language but when we change portal language to Galician, displays the month names in English (January, February, etc) instead of Xaneiro, Febreiro...

We have looked into Language_en.properties but we could not find any key that make reference to month names. Any help would be very usefull.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be 100% certain, but Liferay's translation bundles do not contain month names since those are translated by the Java Virtual Machine itself.

The trouble is that Galician is not officially supported locale in Java 8 and earlier. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html

Solution would be to install this 
http://www.javagalician.org/

Comment: Installing javagalician is a good choice. However this solution doesn't work in some cases. For instance with the FastDateFormat from commons-lang-2.6 doesn't work (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-933). But you can use java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance instead and it would work.